# Simple access to network drive in C#

Tags: c#, sql, disk, network-share

I have a situation where I need to access a network drive in C# but the drive letters may be different on each machine where my application will be running.

For example:
On my development PC, the network drive letter looks like this
***M:\engineering\testerdata\configfile.txt***

But on the production test stand machines, the drive letter might be different on each machine depending on how our IT department set them up.  In those cases, there maybe some machines with ***G:\engineering\testerdata\configfile.txt*** and others with ***L:\engineering\testerdata\configfile.txt***.  Regardless, the data will be on a network drive under the folder \engineering\testerdata\configfile.txt.

I’m attempting to write a method that will access this network folder to read a configuration file.  I don’t have to worry about credentials because they are already setup on each machine.  Also, I don’t want to put this is a local working directory as I would have to manually change the setting on approximately 20 PC’s.  Here is what my method looks like.

```
public string DatabaseSelector()
    {
      //This method determines which database to use when reading     configuration data.  If the file does not exist, default to AX.
        string DataBaseToUse = "AX";  //This is the default database
        string DatabasetoUsePath = "\\\\engineering\\testerdata\\configfile.txt";
        StreamReader DBtoUseReader = new StreamReader(DatabasetoUsePath);

        if (File.Exists(DatabasetoUsePath))  // if file exists, read file to determine which database to use.
        {
            DataBaseToUse = DBtoUseReader.ReadToEnd();   // Set to what's in the file.  Will be AX or MACPAC
            if (DataBaseToUse == "MACPAC")  
                return DataBaseToUse;  //Done - using MACPAC
            else
                return "AX";  // regardless of anything else, use AX
        }
       return DataBaseToUse;  // if file doesn't exist, us AX.
    }  // end DatabaseSelector
```

I always get an exception ***“An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The network name cannot be found.”***

For the string DatabasetoUsePath I have also tried *@"\\engineering\testerdata\configfile.txt";*
And
*"\engineering\testerdata\configfile.txt";*
Which will not even compile, I get the message “Unrecognized escape sequence”.

I thought this would be easy to implement considering I have done something very similar for reading a local file on the C: drive, but reading from the network drive is turning out to be more difficult than I thought!  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well `M:\engineering\testerdata\configfile.txt` refers to the `engineering` folder beneath what-ever `M:` is mapped to.  In your Universal Naming Convention (UNC) example of `\\engineering\testerdata\configfile.txt` I would think it is looking for a host called **engineering** which I guess does not exist.  What exactly is `M:` mapped to?  You should be able to just use UNC not not mapped drives - that gets around `M:` and `G:`

Comment: M: and G: represent drive letters on different machines.  I'm trying to get around using drive letters since I don't know what they are.  The data I'm trying to get to is in the \\engineering\testerdata folder.

Comment: Hmm I'm confused - _"On my development PC, the network drive letter looks like this M:\engineering\testerdata\configfile.txt"_ - Don't `M:` and `G:` represent network **mapped** drives?  Just use UNC.  I don't see what the problem is sadly

Comment: Ok. I think I need to read up and understand what UNC means.  This is the first I've heard of it.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered that the exception message might say exactly what is wrong? That the file path passed to `File.Exists` really doesn't exist? Just try to open the UNC path you pass to `File.Exists` in a Windows Explorer window and see if something is found or not.

Comment: I'm 100% sure the path is correct and the file exists.

Comment: Gotta love the down vote for asking a question.

Comment: Why is this tagged ibm-midrange?

Comment: I tagged Ibm-midrange because depending on what's read in the file, I will connect to an AS-400 database or AX SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the mapping and use the canonical file (I think it is called like that) name instead
For instance I have a drive mapped to I, but it really is

```
\\DC1\applications\
```

normally I would adress this via I:\
You can get this information from the explorer, it really shows in my case that 
I:\ is really \DC1\applications

That would mean that if there is such a thing as I:\engineering you would address it as \DC1\applications\engineering

To view the mapping right click the start button and click open windows explorer. The mapping are displayed on the left under the node of computer. Assuming you have those mappings already.

[image]

See in this example the Y drive is mapped to

```
\\Storage\public
```

The C drive is a local disk, so is D, E is a DVD, F is also a drive, ...

Comment: Though a fine answer, consider adjusting your example to suite the OP's path (well the part after the hostname anyway) :)

Comment: Took your advice in consideration and modified my answer a bit. Useful comment.

Comment: The full path on my machine is M:\\GVR-ARRAY02\engineering\testerdata\configfile.txt.  When I code it as such it still does not find the file on the network.  I'm not sure why I'm having such a difficult time with this.

Comment: The question is what M:\ is, right click the start button, and click windows explorer, open the computer node and see what appears underneeth. The unc should appear.

Comment: Updated my answer with a view of what explorer gives on my pc that has a network drive as well.

Comment: So, were you able to find out the required information ? Please mark me as answer if you were.

Comment: @MTH What everyone is saying is that "M:\" is merely an alias for the object's real path (the "UNC"). If you use the actual UNC, you shouldn't need "M:\" at all. Drive letters aren't actually needed for many references.

Comment: @PhillipStuyck, I think that did it!  I was reading the network drive as just ''Storage" to use your example above.  I added \\Storage\Public or in my case "\\Enginering\Share\\testerdata\configfile.txt".  I didn't understand that's how the folder was to be accessed.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use UNC paths: `\\fqdn\sharename\PathToFile`